# Postgres memory calculation effective_cache_size

Tags: postgresql, configuration, postgresql-9.4

I am verifying some of the configuration in my production Postgres instance. Our DB server has 32 GB RAM. From `pg_settings`, I see that `effective_cache_size` is set to:

```
postgres=> select name, setting, unit from pg_settings where name like 'effective_cache_size'; 
         name         | setting | unit 
----------------------+---------+------
 effective_cache_size | 7851762 | 8kB
(1 row)
```

As per my understanding, this value accounts to 7851762 X 8 KB = 62.8 GB. If my calculation is right, we are basically telling the optimizer that we have 62 GB for this parameter whereas we have only 32 GB of physical RAM.

Please correct me if I am calculating this parameter wrong. I always get confused with calculating parameter allocations for units with 8 KB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7851762 times 8 kB is approximately 60 GB.

I would configure the setting to 30 GB if the machine is dedicated to the PostgreSQL database.

This parameter tells PostgreSQL how much memory there is available for caching its files. If the value is high, PostgreSQL will estimate nested loop joins with an index scan on the inner side cheaper, because it assumes that the index will probably be cached.

Comment: How much this can be effective on speed? can we give lot of ram(assume 20% of database size) to Postgresql and expect it to cache indexes + data into ram?

Comment: It does not influence the memory utilization of PostgreSQL at all. That is determined by the memory available on your machine, the concurrent processes and settings like `shared_buffers`, `work_mem` and `max_connections`. All that `effective_cache_size` influences is how much memory PostgreSQL *thinks* is available for caching. So it influences the estimated cost of index scans.

Comment: just curious ... the calculation would be 7851762 * 8 * 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 ~ 59.90 GiB, right?

Comment: @vrms That is right.